# gradle tar task not executed

Tags: gradle, tar

I am writing a Gradle build for a non-java project for assembling existing directories and tar archives into a .tar.gz The tar task skips if I use the definition like so:

```
task archive(dependsOn: 'initArchive',type: Tar) << {
    baseName = project.Name
    destinationDir = new File(project.buildDir.path+'/installer')
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    from (archiveDir)
    doLast{
        checksum(archivePath)
    }
}
```

here's the console output

```
:jenkins-maven-sonar:archive
Skipping task ':jenkins-maven-sonar:archive' as it has no source files.
:jenkins-maven-sonar:archive UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 9.056 secs
```

When I try to use tar task as a method it fails complaining cannot find method

```
task archive(dependsOn: 'initArchive') << {
    tar{
    baseName = project.Name
    destinationDir = new File(project.buildDir.path+'/installer')
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    from (archiveDir)
    doLast{
        checksum(archivePath)
    }
    }
}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/anadi/Code/da-ci-installers/build.gradle' line: 29

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jenkins-maven-sonar:archive'.
> Could not find method tar() for arguments [build_6a2bckppv2tk8qodr6lkg5tqft$_run_closure3_closure5_closure7@4a5f634c] on task ':jenkins-maven-sonar:archive'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.749 secs
```

Can we run the tar task in same way as Gradle allows running copy? In the same build I have a block like follows and I want to know if tar can used in the same way

```
            copy {
                project.logger.info("Copying bundle :: "+bundle[x])
                from(rootProject.projectDir.path+"/3rd-party-tools/"+bundle[x]) {
                    include '**/*.*'
                }
                into(archiveDir)
           }
```

if not how to make sure my build does not "skip tar" task if using the first form described above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have fallen for the classical mistake of configuring a task in the *execution phase* rather than the *configuration phase*. The solution is to remove the `<<` in the first code snippet.

If you find the `<<` (and the difference it makes) confusing, a good solution is to never use `<<` but always the more explicit `doLast {}`.

There is no `tar` method, but it's usually better to make these things a separate task anyway. (Methods like `copy` should only be preferred over the corresponding task if there is a strong reason.)

Comment: inconceivable?   I hit this problem too without that mistake.  My code that generated the path created a path that didn't exist (hence, no source files).  so, when weirdness happens log the path and check it too if its not a configuration-v-execution problem

Comment: Note, that left-shift operator is currently deprecate and is to be removed in future releases: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/task-leftshift-closure-deprecation-clarification/20599

Answer (score 0):

I had a funny situation where I got hit by this when using doLast{} on a tar task.

It was because of a multi-project build:

```
build.gradle
--> sub-project
    --> build.gradle
```

In this case if you try to have a `tar` or a `copy` task in the main build file that references something from that `project(":sub-project")` uses it will tempt the developer to wrap it in doLast.

For example, main build.gradle file has:

```
  task distTar(type: Tar, dependsOn: "buildDist") {
    description "Package ProjName into a Tar file"
    group "Build"
    baseName = 'outbasename'
    archiveName = baseName + '.tar.gz'
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    destinationDir = file(project(":packaging").buildDir.path)
    extension = 'tar.gz'
    into('outdir') {
      from project(":sub-project").war
    }
  }
```

So they got an error that `project(":sub-project").war` doesn't exist. So to get around it someone put `doLast {}` the task and errors went away. BAD!!

```
  task distTar(type: Tar, dependsOn: "buildDist") {
    doLast { // <-- BAD!!
      description "Package ProjName into a Tar file"
      group "Build"
      baseName = 'outbasename'
      archiveName = baseName + '.tar.gz'
      compression = Compression.GZIP
      destinationDir = file(project(":packaging").buildDir.path)
      extension = 'tar.gz'
      into('outdir') {
        from project(":sub-project").war
      }
    }
  }
```

Then i was left to fix it. So the correct was to do it was to add

`evaluationDependsOn ":sub-project"`

In the main build.gradle file. Now it knows to evaluate it. I remove the incorrect `doLast{}` block and now the task is no longer ignored.